# C/C++ : Update text using DrawText with winapi

Tags: c++, c, winapi

I am writing a simple windows application, in which I want to display to the user two variables : NC and NL.
When a certain action is done by the user, NC and NL are updated (response to WM_COMMAND)

So I am using DrawText in response to WM_PAINT message to display these values. Unfortunately, when the values changes, the message won't update, whereas WM_PAINT is effectively called again. (checked and re-checked)

I want to precise that I also tried with TextOut, but the updated text overlapped on the old text, even if I cleared the screen. I also tried to update the text directly in response to WM_COMMAND, without better success. I didn't find any valuable help on the Internet nor in Windows help.

Isolated the problem in a blank project, I cannot identify the problem. Here is a piece of code.

```
    case WM_PAINT:
    //writeText(mainWnd, "                                ", RGB(0, 25, 255), 410, 10);

    //writeText(mainWnd, buff, RGB(0, 25, 255), 410, 10);
    //sprintf(buff, "piece : %s", isCaval ? "cavalier" : "roi");
    //writeText(mainWnd, buff, RGB(0, 255, 25), 410, 40);
{

    static char buff[250] = { '\0' };
    sprintf(buff, "board : %d x %d", NC, NL);
    static PAINTSTRUCT ps;
    static HDC hDC = BeginPaint(mainWnd, &ps);
    static RECT rect = { 250,250,400,400 };
    SetTextColor(hDC, RGB(255, 0, 0));

    //SetBkMode(hDC, TRANSPARENT);
    DrawText(hDC, buff, strlen(buff), &rect, DT_CENTER);
    EndPaint(mainWnd, &ps);
}
```

How on earth can I get the displayed text succesfully updating as soon as NC or NL changes ?

Comment: Responses to `WM_COMMAND` messages that change the display should call `InvalidateRect` and the system will then issue the `WM_PAINT` message. Aside: shouldn't there be a `break` or `return` at the end of the `case` code block?

Comment: You must remove `static` from `HDC hDC`, that forces the value to be initialized only once. Also `PAINTSTRUCT` doesn't need `static`.

Comment: @BarmakShemirani That's true, thanks you. I removed the static key-word (that I had added believing it could improve the things).

Comment: @WeatherVane Yes, there was a break or return at the end, just forgot to copy/paste it
 Adding the InvalidateRect with a rect from GetClientRect made it to work ! THANKS YOU SO MUCH ! I was stuck there for hours, I am pretty new to winAPI

Comment: If this control just shows a plain text, why don't you use a static control. Setting a text to a static control is much easier...

Comment: You should also remove `static` from the declarations of `ps` and `buff`. The ` = { '\0' }` for initializing `buff` isn't necessary, as the following `sprintf` will overwrite `buf` anyway.